# Grouped and Ungrouped Data- What's the difference?

Tags: classification, dataset

Would data in two columns such as Shoe Size (variate x) and Number of Pairs (frequency f) be considered grouped or ungrouped data? Does grouped data necessarily imply the existence or classification via class intervals?

Answer (score 1):

It is ungrouped data. Moreover, it is not necessary for grouped data to have class intervals.